# MediaPlayer.getDuration() gives incorrect value or 0 in Android 2.1

Tags: android, media-player, duration

> I am working on a streaming audio application in android.I am getting
>   the following issues in the android media player.
>
> ```
>          1 MediaPlayer.getDuration() method returning 0 at sometime 
>          but still its playing the song.
>        2 some times MediaPlayer.getDuration() method returning wrong duration.
>     **Some more info**
>        1 I am caching the files from the server to the sdcard and
>          streaming it to the media player through local http.
>        2 All songs which is streamed is only mp3 files.
>        3 Gives Correct duration when the network is good.
>
>        If you guys find any fixes please direct me to the possible solution.
>
> Thanks in advance.
> ```